# How to match a string variable with several special characters in a Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, string-matching

I'm trying to a script in JS (which I'm fairly new to) in which a user can input a string in x-SAMPA, a notation for transcribing pronunciation, and output the corresponding string in IPA, another such notation. Without any apparently better way of doing it, I have a (quite large) dictionary that maps each x-SAMPA character to its IPA counterpart. (For the sake of completeness: https://pastebin.com/srjEYAGU) I also want to be able to swap the key/value pairs and re-use the table for IPA ---> x-SAMPA.

Since `str.replace()` only replaces the first instance (requiring a global search) *and* I'm trying to match a string *variable*, not a string *literal*, I guess I have to do this with a `RegExp()`:

```
sInput = "TIs TIN Iz r\\ON"

Object.keys(xsampaToIPAMain).forEach(function(key) {
    sInput = sInput.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), xsampaToIPAMain[key]);
});
console.log(sInput);
```

But, 1) x-SAMPA isn't a 1:1 correspondence between sounds and characters; in this case the two characters "r\" collectively refer to one sound, so I can't just go substituting character by character, and 2) x-SAMPA incorporates lots of special regex characters. In particular, as soon as it reaches the first key in the table with backslashes:

```
    "h\\":   "ɦ",
```

Regex throws an error:

```
"Invalid regular expression: /h\/: \ at end of pattern"
```

Searching around it seems regex first escapes `\\` to `\` and then tries to escape the next character, and so the pattern to find is really `h\\\\`.

I can't search something like `key+"\\"` since most keys don't have any backslashes to try to work around and so they'll just crash the regex.
And then there are the other special regex characters like `?` and `}` and `.` that are also x-SAMPA characters that need to be escaped but not, as far as I can tell, the same as backslashes).

So -
what would be the least messy way to replace all instances of a variable string of varying length with special regex characters that need to be escaped?

Comment: Note that double backslashes in a string will evaluate to a string with a *single* backslash, eg `'\\'.length === 1`. That's a JS thing and not just a regex thing

Comment: Can you provide a real input data and the desired response?